# List all Databricks catalogs / schema / tables in workspace without Premium account and Unity Catalog

Tags: databricks

As I understand it, if I want to use the Databricks SDK or Databricks information schema to list existing Databricks catalogs / schema / tables I need Unity Catalog. To have Unity Catalog I need a Premium account.

How can I programmatically list Databricks catalogs / schema / tables for non-Premium accounts?

Comment: For anyone interested, in Unity Catalog joined premium workspaces that would be:

    SELECT DISTINCT schema_name FROM system.information_schema.schemata;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catalogs are only objects of the Unity Catalog, without it each workspace use Hive Metastore for which there is no API for listing, so you need to use a combination of `show databases` and `show tables in <database_name` from the notebook. You can look into [this diagram builder](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/database-diagram-builder) code as a reference.